# Simplification of a basic set expression

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This is a really basic problem that I already have the answer for but I cant come to it myself.
How do I simplify the following expression: (A'⋃ B) ⋃ (A ⋃ B')'
The answer should be:(A'⋃ B)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use \cup as an infix operator, not \bigcup.

Comment: Hint: Use de Morgan's law to expand $(A' \cup B)'$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint . $(A\cup B')'=A'\cap B$

because $x\in (A\cup B')'\iff$ $ x\not\in A\cup B'\iff$ $ (x\not\in A\land x\not\in B')\iff$ $ (x\in A'\land x\in B).$

Also, if $C\subset A'$ then $(A'\cup B)\cup C=A'\cup B.$ For example if $C=A'\cap B$.